# Converting code using list built so far, to a generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I am aware how the `yield` keyword is used in python to return the generators some thing like this

```
def example_function():
    for i in xrange(1, 10)
        yield i
```

But I have code like this

```
def feed_forward(self,inputs):
    activations = [inputs]
    for I in xrange(len(self.weights)):
        activation = activations[i].dot(self.weights[i])
        activations.append(activation)
    return activations
```

Where the list going to be created is itself required in the iteration inside the function.

How do I rewrite the code to more pythonic code, by using the `yield` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.append()` calls and the initial list definition with `yield` statements. You are using the preceding result each time in the next iteration of the loop, simply record the last 'activation' and re-use that:

```
def feed_forward(self, inputs):
    yield inputs
    activation = inputs
    for weight in self.weights:
        activation = activation.dot(weight)
        yield activation
```

Comment: @Goutam: ah, of course. It's the previous value, really. I'll correct.

Comment: Is it possible return generators in reverse order?

Comment: @Goutam: no; generators are a way of writing iterators, and iterators go one way. The only option is to capture all output in a list, then reversing the list.

Comment: Is it pythonic to do that?

Comment: @Goutam: What problem are you trying to solve? Can you not just produce the results in reverse order?